# list indexing with [[ vs [ and NULL

Tags: r, list, null

If I create a list

```
mylist = list()
```

```
mylist[1] <- "test"
```

`[[` returns:

```
mylist[[1]]
# [1] "test"
```

`[` returns:

```
mylist[1]
# [[1]]
# [1] "test"
```

## But in the case where

```
mylist = list()
```

why does

```
mylist[1]
```

Result in

```
[[1]]
NULL
```

But

```
mylist[[1]]
```

Does not return `NULL` it -- returns an error?

```
Error in mylist[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: This section of Advanced R can help: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#subsetting-oob

Comment: I see a question mark in your post but I don't really see a question. You have correctly described the behavior but what exactly do you expect from an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a `list` as:

```
mylist  = list()
mylist[[1]] = c(1,2,3)
mylist[[2]] = c(4,5,6)
```

In the concept of list we can say `mylist` has two layers which can be accessed by `[[` and there element can be accessed by`[` like:

```
mylist[[1]][2]
```

In your case `mylist` has no layer so when you do `mylist[1]` R defaultly access first layer and says there are no elements in the first layer of `mylist` and returns `NULL` but when you do `mylist[[1]]` R says `Out of Bounds` because the first layer of `mylist` has been called and there is no layer at all. That's why R throws error in `[[` case.

Comment: Why won't `mylist <- list();mylist[["foo"]]` yield an error?

Comment: @jay.sf  First of all you can't pass a character for an Index.

Comment: Yes I can, try `mylist <- list(foo="test") ;mylist[["foo"]]`.